# Fitting a rectangle inbetween existing, non-overlapping rectangles

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, rectangles

I have a problem that can perhaps best be illustrated with windows on a computer screen: create another window, as large as possible, not overlapping any of the existing windows.

In other words: given a set of N rectangles on a finite surface (a sheet of paper, or a screen), find the largest rectangle that can be fitted inbetween these rectangles.  (Coordinates can be arbitrary, so a bitmap is not a viable solution here.)

The following photo shows three rectangles (in black) and the largest rectangle that can be fitted (in red).

http://www.irstafoto.se/blogmtrl/rectangle-illustration.jpg

I have written a naive algorithm for this which considers all pairs of x- and y-coordinates used by the rectangles.  It is, unfortunately, O(N^5) because in the worst case each rectangle candidate must be checked against every other rectangle for overlapping.

Is there anything better?

```
       max_area = 0;
       max_rect = nil

       xc = all rectangle x-coordinates [x1, ..., x6] in picture)
       yc = all rectangle y-coordinates (y1, ..., y6] in picture)
       xc = [0] + xc + [W]; /* W is width of area */
       yc = [0] + yc + [H]; /* H is height of area */

       sort(xc);
       sort(yc);

       for each x0 in xc
           for each x1 > x0 in xc
               for each y0 in yc
               for each y1 > y0 in yc
                       r = rect(x0,y0,x1,y1)
                       if (area(r) > max_area and !overlapping(r))
                           max_area = area(r)
                           max_rect = r
```

Comment: Yes.  You can do considerably better with a "scan line algorithm," which is the right google search term.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

Sort on X and Y independently so that you can map all corner coordinates to an integer index in range [0,2N].

Fill a binary image with black where space is occupied by a rectangle *in the reduced coordinates*. The image size will be (2N+1)x(2N+1).

[image]

Find the maximal rectangles that you can place in the white area. This can be done in time proportional to the image area. (See the article "Object descriptors based on a list of rectangles: method and algorithm".)

Then for every maximal rectangle, compute the actual area, given the true coordinates, and keep the largest

This should be an overall O(N²) procedure.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't think of an affine transformation from x- or y-coordinates to integer values in the range [0,2N-1].

Comment: There is no need to compute the transform at all, you just replace the values by their rank. What you get is a "logical" image, not a scaled one, just the ordering matters (my picture relates to yours). You can even implement the algorithm without explicitly representing this image.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this transformation is affine so it doesn't report a false maximum.  For instance, if A and B are rectangles such that area(A) > area(B) but in transformed coordinates area(A') < area(B').

Comment: @KjellPost: sorry, but you really don't understand how the transform works.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?  Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what I did, based on you figure.

Comment: The problem, as I see it, is that a potential wide area to the right is "compressed" into a thin column and would not be detected, as in the following example: http://www.irstafoto.se/blogmtrl/rect2.png

Comment: Wrong. You don't understand the transform nor the beforelast paragraph.

Comment: Why don't you show me how the example in http://www.irstafoto.se/blogmtrl/rect2.png looks like after your transformation?

Comment: Hem, don't you see the embedded image ? This is the real mapping for your original illustration.

Comment: Your method may work on my original example, but it also needs to work on http://www.irstafoto.se/blogmtrl/rect2.png in order to be useful.

Comment: It does work on any case. For this other image, merge the empty columns.

Comment: Perfect. Now enumerate ALL maximal rectangles (9 of them I think; single row/column counts) and compute their true area (in the original image).

Comment: How do you go about enumerating those rectangles then?

Comment: Check the cited article or lookup "maximal rectangles in a binary image". there is an O(N²) solution.

Comment: Yes, but the solution in the transformed space does not correspond to the solution in the original space.

Comment: You still don't understand it. Can you list the 9 maximal rectangles ?

Comment: What do you call a rectangle candidate ?

Answer (score 0):

What about semi quad-tree approach? You could create a node with 9 properties, the rectangle itself, 4 rectangles with area that is available north, south, east and west of the node's current rectangle; and finally 4 nodes each having subtree in corresponding areas. Node class would look something like this:

```
class node 
{
    public var nr:Rectangle;
    public var sr:Rectangle;
    public var wr:Rectangle;
    public var er:Rectangle;

    public var nn:node = null;
    public var sn:node = null;
    public var wn:node = null;
    public var en:node = null;

    public var rect:Rectangle;
}
```

When creating a new node you should just clip bounding area with lines containing sides of current rectangle. This is not a typical quad-tree. Here subnode's areas may overlap.

Two more essential actions. First adding the rectangle. Starting with first solid rectangle you create a node and then for each of remaining rectangles you add them to the tree. To add rectangle to node you should check if it overlaps any of its areas. If so, clip it to the area and push it down to that node. If node is empty (or null) create a new one.

Finally finding a largest rectangle. This is done recursively starting at the root node. You should get the largest rectangle from those that cover all 4 areas. It is quite easy as you already have them as properties of your node. There is one trick however - if there is a subnode in this area you should use this nodes largest rect (here's the recursion).