# What is a good data structure to use to store rectangles when I want & efficiently search for all areas contains at least a given size

Tags: algorithm

So I have a non-overlapping set of rectangles and I want to efficiently determine where a rectangle of a given size can fit.  Oh, also it will need to be reasonably efficient at updating as I will be “allocating” the space based on some other constraints once I find the possible valid locations.

The “complicated part” is the rectangles can touch (for example a rectangle at (0,0) 100 units wide and 50 units tall and a second rectangle at (0,50) and 50x50 allows a fit of a 50 wide by 80 tall rectangle at (0,0) through (0,20).   Finding a fit may involve “merging” more then two rectangles.

(note: I'll be starting with a small number of adjacent rectangles, approximately 3, and removing rectangular areas as I "allocate" them.  I expect the vast number of these allocations will not exactly cover an existing rectangle, and will leave me with 2 more more newer rectangles.)

At first I thought I could keep two “views” of my rectangles, one preferring to break in the y-axis to keep the widest possible rectangles and another that breaks in the x-axis to keep the talles possible and then I could do...um...something clever to search.

Then I figured “um, people have been working on this stuff for a long time and just because I can’t figure out how to construct the right google query it doesn’t mean this isn’t some straightforward application of quad trees or r-lists I have somehow forgotten to know about”

So is there already a good solution to this problem?

(So what am I **really doing**?  I'm laser cutting features into the floor of a box.  Features like 'NxM circles 1.23" in diameter with 0.34" separations'.  The floor starts as a rectangle with small rectangles already removed from the corners for supports.  I'm currently keeping a list of unallocated rectangles sorted by y with x as the tie breaker, and in some limited cases I can do a merge between 2 rectangles in that list if it produces a large enough result to fit my current target into.  That doesn't really work all that well.   I could also just place the features manually, but I would rather write a program for it.)

(Also: how many “things” am I doing it to?  So far my boxes have had 20 to 40 “features” to place, and computers are pretty quick so some really inefficient algorithm may well work, but this is a hobby project and I may as well learn something interesting as opposed to crudely lashing some code together)

Ok, so absent a good answer to this, I came at it from another angle.
I took a look at all my policies and came up with a pretty short list: "allocate anywhere it fits", "allocate at a specific x,y position", and "allocate anywhere with y>(specific value)".

I decided to test with a pretty simple data structure.  A list of non-overlapping rectangles representing space that is allocatable.  Not sorted, or merged or organized in any specific way.  The closest to interesting is I track extents on rectangles to make retrieving min/max X or Y quick.

I made myself a little function that checks an allocation at a specific position, and returns a list of rectangles blocking the allocation all trimmed to the intersection with the prospective allocation (and produce a new free list if applicable).   I used this as a primitive to implement all 3 policies.

"allocate at a specific x,y position" is trivial, use the primitive if you see no blocking rectangles that allocation is successful.

I implemented "allocate anywhere" as "allocate with y>N" where N is "minimum Y" from the free list.

"allocate where y>N" starts with x=min-X from the free list and checks for an allocation there.  If it finds no blockers it is done.  If it finds blockers it moves x to the max-X of the blocker list.  If that places the right edge of the prospective allocation past max-X for the free list then x is set back to min-X for the free list and y is set to the minimum of all the max-Y's in all the blocking lists encountered since the last Y change.

For my usage patterns I also get some mileage from remembering the size of the last failed allocation (with N=minY), and fast failing any that are at least as wide/tall as the last failure.

Performance is fast enough for my usage patterns (free list starting with one to three items, allocations in the tens to forties).

Comment: (This question deserves a better title. I read *axis-parallel rectangle*, in the context of *computational geometry* (tag thus!) I used to be used to *rect* used for such. What if I transform width into, say, *a-coordinates* and height into *b-coordinates*: looks like a range search but for abutting areas - of which there can be what, n²? Bummer.)

Comment: Is `update` *remove area covered by some rectangle*, *add rectangle to allocate from* or something else, entirely?

Comment: A sort-of-dual problem: [Fitting a rectangle inbetween existing, non-overlapping rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32773224)

Comment: I'll be setting an initial list of rectangles (either one or three rectangles), and from then on I'll only be removing.

Comment: That other fitting problem is "find the largest rectangle that fits".   I never really need to know "largest".   Hmmmm, as far as simplification goes, I think I will tend to want "below this other rectangle if it fits, otherwise as close to the top left as fits", but I'm not sure those are the only "policies" that are useful.     I'll add a little more to the problem statute above.

Comment: It sounds like your top-level problem is to find a valid placement for each of a given set of rectangles inside a given polygon with horizontal and vertical edges.  A simpler version of this problem, in which the initially available space is a rectangle, is called rectangle packing, and unfortunately even that's NP-hard (e.g. by reduction from the bin packing problem), so it's very unlikely any scalable algorithm exists.